# What's the best way to share a dictionary between multiple Python processes?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, data-sharing

All processes would read from and write to this dictionary. I want operations on shared dictionary to be as fast as possible (something like under 50 micro seconds).

Sharing dictionary using multiprocessing.Manager isn't fast enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

50μs is pretty lenient.

Can you treat the dictionary keys as if they were in a memcached datastore ?

This 2009 benchmarking comparison shows python-memcache to be more than fast enough - http://amix.dk/blog/post/19471

There's also dogpile.cache - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dogpile.cache - which can be backed with memcached.

Not sure what the speed hits would be in converting from strings to python objects.

Answer (score -2):

Just using the usual mutex and locks I would think, no ?  lock.acquire(), lock.release() API from 'threading' library should help, http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html

But I don't think you'll win more speed as your design seems to be limited by the 
Python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) which may be the roadblock here.

I may be wrong-